# Don't remember vs. can't remember

Tags: differences, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Could you tell me which is proper in English:

> I don't remember.
>
> I can't remember.

And if both are possible and good English, what is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are both good English, and the difference in actual practice is very slight.

*I don't remember* means that I once knew, but now I do not.  This is less committal, since it sounds as if I am not necessarily trying very hard to remember.

*I can't remember* means that I once knew, but now I cannot think of it.   This is more emphatic, since it sounds as if I am testing the limits of my memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a subset of the distinction you make, but *"I don't remember my 21st birthday"* probably means nothing exceptional happened, whereas *"I can't remember my 21st birthday"* probably means you had a lot of celebratory drink! Maybe in some contexts, *can't* implies that your memory wasn't functioning to full capacity at the time you're trying to remember.

Answer (score 4):

They are both good English.

The only difference between them (in my dialect) is that *I can't remember* indicates that the speaker tried to remember, whereas *I don't remember* doesn't imply that.

Thus: *Can you remember what happened that day?* is asking the addressee to try to remember, whereas *Do you remember what happened that day?* is merely asking him whether he happens to remember.

(This answer is similar to [Daniel δ's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61106/3461), but I'm not sure he means what I do.)